# How to make a core persistent on Solr 5.2.1

Tags: apache, solr, jetty

This thing bugs me for sometime now - I've been googling the web and literally nothing on something obvious such as keeping a Solr core persistent on 5.2.1

Each time I restart the service "sudo service solr restart" my cores are getting lost, although the data can still be found in: /var/solr/data.

The [persistence flag](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%20(supported%20through%204.x)) is [no longer supported in 5.x](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Moving+to+the+New+solr.xml+Format) - so what is the alternative ?

Any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into an issue with a non-persistent core as well. Make sure to check the solr log (/var/solr/logs, in my case) for startup details:

```
ERROR - 2016-04-05 05:05:49.547; [   ]
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException;
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
Found multiple cores with the name [somecore],
with instancedirs
[/var/solr/data/somecore/] and [/var/solr/data/gettingstarted/]
```

The `gettingstarted` core (a sample created on solr installation) had the same core name set in its `core.properties`.

Deleting the `gettingstarted` directory resolved this issue.

Comment: That's ace! Thanks for following up on this.

Answer (score 2):

Solr uses core discovery now, so the `persistent` flag isn't needed. Any core available in the data dir should be loaded automagically. You might still need the solr.xml file, although it should be enough to just have an empty `<solr>` element.

The content within the core directory (conf, data, core.properties) should also be present.

Comment: Great input - I believe the issue is that I am using an oudated solr.xml, which is required as I am using it with my rails application. Without the solr.xml produced by sunspot I do not get it working. I am somewhat in a pickle. On the other hand I tried to create a new core leaving it as it is, restarting solr and it still wasn't found - so perhaps something wrong with my installation. Since I had a timeline to hit we opt for elastic search re-writing bits of the application. Sounds silly - but I have a little more knowledge in that area. But I will will familiarise myself with solr soon.

Comment: Sunspot shouldn't require anything in particular in solr.xml. Probably in solrconfig.xml (which configures the responsehandlers, caching, etc. - everything useful for a core) or schema.xml (which is generated from your rails definitions) - solr.xml was used previously to support multicore setups, but these setups are autodiscovered now (there's a few other settings for solr.xml as well, but they're not relevant to just get it to work). Are you using the Solr distributed with sunspot, or are you using a separate installation?